# Types of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was given this question. It asked to state which of the sequences, $a_n$, $b_n$ and $u_n$ are divergent, convergent or periodic.

The given info is:

$$u_1 = 1 \\
u_n\cdot u_{n+1} =2\\ 
a_n = u_{n+1} + u_n\\
b_n = u_{n+1} - u_n$$

I got $u_n$ to be $1,2,1,2,\dots$

$a_n$ to be $3,3,3,3,3,\dots$

$b_n$ to be $1,-1,1,-1,1,\dots$

So granted that I worked these out correctly.  I'm guessing $u_n$ and $b_n$ are periodic, however I'm not sure about $a_n$.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question and equations properly using [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It is quite unclear what you are after at the moment.

Comment: Take a bit more time in deciding which tags to tag your question with.  The tag (self-learning) for example should only be used for questions about pedagogy and the actual action of learning on your own (*E.g. how frequently should I give myself homework and practice mock exams if I'm teaching myself such and such topic*).  It should never be used on a question which is about the content of what it is you are studying rather than a question about the process of studying.  Similarly, (proof-theory) is an irrelevant tag here as well.

Comment: Yes, your conclusions look correct for $U_n$ and $a_n$. However, $b_1=U_2-U_1=2-1=1$, $b_2=U_3-U_2=1-2=-1$, $b_4=U_5-U_4=1-2=1$,... The classification would label $U_n$ periodic, $a_n$ periodic and convergent, and $b_n$ periodic and divergent.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft okay thanks. So I'm guessing $a_n$ converges to 3 ? Also I don't get how $b_n$  is divergent

Comment: Please check that I have typeset the equations correctly.  As for the content of the question, every sequence which is not convergent is said to be divergent, but the types of divergence can be classified further.  Assuming your work is correct, $a_n$ would appear to be a constant sequence which is an example of a convergent sequence.  Both $b_n$ and $u_n$ appear to be divergent periodic sequences.  These should be proven if you want to be certain.  Induction would be a good tool to use here.

Comment: To show that $b_n$ is divergent and periodic, try to prove the claim that $b_{n+4}=b_n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: To be convergent the terms of the sequence should get arbitrarily close to some value. In particular, they would get close to each other as well. But the distance between two consecutive terms of $b_n$ is not smaller than $2$.

Comment: $a_n$ is also periodic in a trivial way: period 1.

Comment: Okay thanks for all the help . I was having a look back at it and would it be reasonable to state that $u_n$ is divergent and periodic since the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: For the sole reason of the limit not existing?  No.  The sequence $1,2,3,4,5,\dots,n,\dots$ doesn't have a limit that exists but it certainly isn't periodic.  To show that a sequence $f_n$ is periodic, you must find the period, $p$, and some starting point $N$, and show that $f_{n}=f_{n+p}$ for all $n\geq N$.  All that showing that the limit doesn't exist accomplishes is to show that the sequence is divergent, but it doesn't show in what way it is divergent.